# Symfony can't connect to MySQL Docker container

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, dockerfile

I have three Docker containers running on Mac OS sierra, namely `web`, `mysql` and `mongo`, and have linked both `mongo` and `mysql` into `web`, which is essentially a Ubuntu Xenail base, with Apache and PHP added.

I am currently mounting my local Symfony project into the `web` container, and that seems to be working fine, but when I try to interact with the DB in any way, I get:

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused

I've tried almost every combination of parameter values, but keep getting the same result.

I suspect it might have something to do with the way that I am linking the containers?

I'm in the process of learning Docker, so please excuse my limited knowledge.

Thanks!

**Web dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
MAINTAINER Some Guy <someguy@domain.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
apache2 \
vim \
php \
php-common \
php-cli \
php-curl \
php-mysql \
php-mongodb \
libapache2-mod-php \
php-gd

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/symfony.local/public_html
RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/symfony.local/public_html

RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www

COPY config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY config/apache/sites-available/*.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN a2ensite symfony.local.conf

EXPOSE  80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

**Mysql dockerfile:**

```
FROM mysql:5.7
MAINTAINER Some Guy <someguy@domain.com>

# Set the root users password
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password

# Copy over the DB dump to be run upon creation
COPY sql/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# Copy over the custom mysql config file
COPY config/ /etc/mysql/conf.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

**Run commands:**

```
docker run --name mongo -d mongo #Im making use of the official Mongo image
docker run --name mysql -v /usr/local/var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d someguy/local:mysql
docker run --name web -d -p 80:80 --link mysql:mysql --link mongo:mongo -v ~/Sites/symfony.local/:/var/www/symfony.local/public_html/ someguy/local:web
```

**Symfony parameters.yml file:**

```
parameters:
    database_host: mysql
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: gorilla
    database_user: root
    database_password: password
```

**UPDATE:**

So I've moved over to using `docker-compose`, but am still receiving the same error.

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ~/Sites/symfony.local/:/var/www/symfony.local/public_html/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: This probably has little to do with Docker per se. How did you configure remote access in MySQL?

Comment: Not sure that I did, I just extended the official mysql image and set the `sql_mode`. Would one need to configure remote access even when the image is directly linked to the web container?

Comment: Don't be confused by this Docker "linking" -- each container is seen as a host on the Docker network. You may want to read up on Docker networking (and on configuring MySQL remote access).

Comment: I would suggest using docker-compose, it'll simplify setting up all the containers and create links between the containers. I did this with Symfony and just had to use the db containers name in paramters.yml to get it working.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks, will look into it, appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @mickadoo Thanks, I'm in the process of moving over to docker-compose as we speak. Do you perhaps have a sample `docker-compose.yml` file that worked with your Symfony setup, that I could use as reference?

Comment: I don't have any publicly viewable but the one I made was based on this: https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Means, it has nothing to do with your network per se - the links are just fine.

What you are lacking is the how the user has been created, if the user has been created https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c207cc19a272a6bfe1916c964ed8df47f18479e7/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L122 .. so actually without a host limitation per se.

The question in your case is, what is inside your "sql/" folder - those scripts are executed during the entrypoint.

Be sure to never use exitX in those scripts, they will interrupt the main script, see https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c207cc19a272a6bfe1916c964ed8df47f18479e7/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L151

Check your docker logs for mysql to ensure the script did not print you any warnings, use https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c207cc19a272a6bfe1916c964ed8df47f18479e7/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh as an reference.

And last but not least, please use **docker-compose**. If you have issues with the timings ( mysql starting to slow and your web-container freaks out ), use a "wait for mysql" entrypoint in web:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script does only exist to wait for the database before we fire up tomcat / standalone

RET=1
echo "Waiting for database"
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    sleep 1;
    if [ -z "${db_password}" ]; then
        mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -e "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; RET=$?
    else
        mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_password -e "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; RET=$?
    fi
done
```

Set `db_host`, `$user`, `$pasword` accordingly using ENV or whatever suits you.

Comment: So after quite a bit of suffering, it turns out that MySQL was taking it's sweet time to initiate, as you stated in your answer @EugeneMayer, longer than 2 minutes, which is what caused the issue. After running `docker-compose up -d`, and then running `docker-compose logs` to have a look at what was going on, I noticed that MySQL never finished starting up. After waiting for it to finish booting up, I was able to connect using the host name and corresponding parameters. Thanks!

Comment: That is very very Slow. Are you using OSX with a Host mount for/var/lib/MySQL ?

Comment: Yup, agreed. I am running OSX, no Host mount though.

Comment: That looks quite promising. Will give it a try, thanks for the assist!