# Symfony 4 connection on Mysql docker container

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker

I use docker for MySql and Adminer interface, the connection between Adminer and MySql works but the Symfony connection is refused. Symfony isn't in a container.

What can i do for the connection between Symfony 4 and MySql container works ?

this is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
      MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    links:
      - mysql:db

volumes:
  mysql:
```

my .env on symfony 4:

```
# This file defines all environment variables that the application needs.
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE.
# Use ".env.local" for local overrides during development.
# Use real environment variables when deploying to production.
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=825aa371242c34bdcc0c693ac4241bcf
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^localhost|example\.com$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://testuser:testpassword@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname

###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

and my doctrine.yml :

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    #env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        unix_socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

**UPDATE**

---

Well, thanks for your help it works, 
Symfony or more especially doctrine not found the container, like you said I exposed the Mysql port, but I have to make an other change :
This line works for me :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
```

and not this line :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://testuser:testpassword@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
```

In fact it seems like that my docker-compose up doesn't work very well and compose with old version, docker doesn't "see" my change on docker-compose.yml, so the password and user stay "root". 
I'm going to try this :
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-delete-cache/5753/2
and this:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1487

Sometimes, database need to be delete => Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony can't connect to MySQL Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387390/symfony-cant-connect-to-mysql-docker-container)

Comment: @Cid, not a duplicate. Hence the part where the OP mentions that symfony is NOT in a docker. This changes the whole nature of the issue

Comment: And @cisco_bro, is there a specific reason why your symfony is not in a docker?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort i try to have the most simple config, i already try to use Symfony in a container but I encountered the same problem.

Comment: @cisco_bro Your username and password might need to be [URL Encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) if they contains specials characters.

Comment: @Cid Yes but I use the "url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'"

Comment: @cisco_bro I declare everything (hostname, db name, username, password and so on...) in doctrine.yml. (and this should be the case when your site will be in production, no .env for prod)

Comment: This is because of collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci. I am working on some projects . I face this issue when I use collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but If I change collate: utf8_genral_ci, it starts accepting connection request

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose database port like eg.

```
version: '3'
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
      MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    links:
      - mysql:db

volumes:
  mysql:
```

and then in `.env` file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://testuser:testpassword@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
```

Make sure that the ip address matches the IP of your docker host.

Comment: I exposed the port and now I have a docker log :
mysql_1_5d6024a6800d | 2018-11-27T15:10:55.985191Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'testuser'@'172.45.0.1' (using password: YES)
It seems like my environnement configuration on docker-compose.yml doesn't work

Comment: Now it is a problem with your mysql account not with docker. You need to allow for remote access for your mysql user